# calculator parsing wth FSM

Tags: fsm

I am trying to remember what I have learned in university where we used fsm + parse tree to build a compiler.

To start off simple I thought I will try to do it for a calculator first.

this is what I have got

[image]

I can't seem to get what I should do if im in the bracket state and I see another `(` and what state I should go to if I see a `)`

I know you can get the result easily with a stack implementation but I want to remember how to do it with FSM.

Comment: oh and I missed a connection between read and bracket